# Writable file in a Ruby Gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I created a Ruby Gem executable that contains a settings.yml file where it stores some settings. These settings can be altered during runtime of the executable. 
On Ubuntu I installed this Gem with sudo gem install and got a write permission error while trying to save the settings.yml file during runtime. So I build the Gem once again this time with write permissions set for all in the settings.yml file. This worked and during runtime I could save my settings.yml file.
But when trying to run the gem on my Raspberry Pi it gave the same write permission error.
Is there a way to ascertain write permissions for a certain file in a Ruby Gem?

Comment: You shouldn't write your `settings.yml` inside the installed gem directory. It is *very* common that the user running your executable has no write permissions there. Instead, access your `settings.yml` from a location which is usually writable by the current user, e.g. the user's home directory as in `File.expand_path("~/my_gem.yml")`. It is also a good idea to make this location configurable (e.g. with a command line parameter).

Comment: Thank you @HolgerJust, this is certainly a better way to get things done.